# gridView show image in emulator perfectly but not in my device

Tags: android, gridview

in my app i am using gridView to show the fetched images from api...
the size of images perfectly fit in emulator but in my device they are overlap and not showing completely.... i have also use

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int)(metrics.density*180f),(int)(metrics.density*250f)));
```

here is my full code...

activity_movie_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:numColumns="2"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
tools:context="com.example.arti.movieapp.MovieGrid">
```

**MovieGrid.java**

```
public class MovieGrid extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<Movie>> {

    private static final int EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID = 1;
    private String URL_request;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    GridView gridView;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_grid);

        metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            URL_request=extras.getString("url");
        }
        Log.v("BookListActivity",URL_request+"&");
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MovieLoader(this,URL_request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> loader, ArrayList<Movie> data) {
       Log.v("MovieGrid","onLoadFinish"+data.size());
        imageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this,data,metrics);
        Log.v("MovieGrid","onLoadFinish"+data.size());
        gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<Movie>> loader)
    {
        //gridView.setAdapter(null);
    }
}
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;

    // references to our images
    private ArrayList<Movie> arraylist;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> arraylist,DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        mContext=context;
        this.arraylist=arraylist;
        this.metrics=metrics;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // getResource() is not recognize here so i pass metrics from MovieGrid to here by constructor
        //DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        ImageView imageView;
        if (view == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int)(metrics.density*180f),(int)(metrics.density*250f)));
            Log.v("height",(int)(metrics.density*250f)+"");
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) view;
        }
        String path = arraylist.get(i).getPosterPath();
        Log.v("ImageAdapter", arraylist.get(i).getPosterPath());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.image_not_avail).into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

**Emulator**

[image: this is shows in emulator]

**Device**

[image: this is shows in my device]

i cannot understand what is the problem here...

Comment: Please provide your R.layout.activity_movie_grid xml code

Comment: now i have added this